# ¿Cómo conectar Laravel-Zero con DocumentDB?

Tags: mongodb, aws

Estoy intentando conectar una base de datos en DocumentDB mediante Laravel,
instalé la librería jenssegers/mongodb para ocupar el ORM de Eloquent con MongoDB.

Ya realicé la configuración correspondiente en mi archivo database.php

```
'mongodb' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
            'database' => "mibase",
            'username' => "miusuario",
            'password' => "mipassword",
            'options' => [                   
                'ssl' => true,
            ],
            'driver_options' => [
                'context' => stream_context_create([
                    'ssl' => [
                        'cafile' => 'archivo.pem',
                        'allow_self_signed' => true,
                        'verify_peer' => true,
                        'verify_peer_name' => true,
                        'verify_expiry' => true,
                    ]
                ])
            ]
        ],
```

Sin embargo al momento de intentar realizar una consulta o inserción, me aparece la siguiente excepción

***Deprecated: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::__construct(): The "context" driver option is deprecated.***

Estoy utilizando la versión 4.0 de jenseggers, la versión 1.6 y dll 1.8 de mongoDB
Y la versión 7.4 de PHP

De antemano gracias por su respuesta

Comment: Hola @BetaM! 
Gracias por responder, verás, estoy de hecho usando Laravel-zero en su versión 2.4

Comment: Si, es un Framework basado en Laravel para aplicaciones por consola, 
https://laravel-zero.com

Comment: O tienes razón! Te lo agradezco, se me olvidó especificar

Answer (score 1):

me apoyó un colega a solucionar el detalle.

Se resolvió cambiando la configuración de la conexión en database.php, agregando un parámetro a '***options***' y quitando el parámetro '***driver_options***', por lo que la conexión quedó de la siguiente forma:

```
'mongodb' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
            'database' => "mibase",
            'username' => "miusuario",
            'password' => "mipassword",
            'options' => [                   
                'ssl' => true,
                'tlsAllowInvalidCertificates'=> true,
            ],
```